# Extracting raw data from bytes object

Tags: boost, python-3.x, boost-python

Using ([unpatched](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4609)) Boost Python, is there a better way to get the raw data out of a Python 3 `bytes` object than this fairly nasty way?

```
  namespace py = boost::python

  py::object raw = <a bytes object>
  int n = py::len(raw);
  char *r = new char[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    r[i] = py::extract<int>(raw[i]);
```

(Boost 1.48 with Python 3.2)